# How to write detect arguments passed in command line in the package.json script section?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, command-line

I have the following *package.json*:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "ng test",
  },
...
}
```

And I want to run the following cmd:

```
npm run test --prod
```

Is there a way of knowing if the `--prod` flag is being passed and run the command `ng test --watch=false --browsers=ChromeHeadless` instead of running the command `ng test`?

Comment: Write your own script and run that as the test script?

Comment: I did that for my real scenario case. I was just wondering if that is something possible to do or if we just need to always write our own script.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the best of doing this is by creating a script with a different name (like prodTest) and add it to the scripts in the package.json with the command you want as value.

Something like:

```
"prodTest" : "ng test --watch=false --browsers=ChromeHeadless"
```